# Error inflating class fragment class not found android.view.fragment but I am including the compatability library?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am seeing a class not found exception for android.view.fragment although I am using the compatibility library.  Compiles fine but crashes.  Is there another package that I should use when pre 3.0?  I already changed all fragment classes to android.support.v4.app.Frament but it still crashes because of what is in the layout. My SDK is 4.03 but device is 2.3.

Here is layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/frag_series"
    android:layout_width="200dip"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    class="com.authorwjf.hello_fragments.ListFrag" />
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/frag_capt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.authorwjf.hello_fragments.DetailFrag" />
</LinearLayout>
```

LogCat:

```
08-08 14:53:21.644: E/AndroidRuntime(13056): Caused by: android.view.InflateException:     Binary    XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
08-08 14:53:21.644: E/AndroidRuntime(13056):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:576)
08-08 14:53:21.644: E/AndroidRuntime(13056):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
08-08 14:53:21.644: E/AndroidRuntime(13056):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
08-08 14:53:21.644: E/AndroidRuntime(13056):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
08-08 14:53:21.644: E/AndroidRuntime(13056):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
08-08 14:53:21.644: E/AndroidRuntime(13056):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:200)
08-08 14:53:21.644: E/AndroidRuntime(13056):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1647)
08-08 14:53:21.644: E/AndroidRuntime(13056):    at com.authorwjf.hello_fragments.Main.onCreate(Main.java:11)
08-08 14:53:21.644: E/AndroidRuntime(13056):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
08-08 14:53:21.644: E/AndroidRuntime(13056):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
08-08 14:53:21.644: E/AndroidRuntime(13056):    ... 11 more
08-08 14:53:21.644: E/AndroidRuntime(13056): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.fragment in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.authorwjf.hello_fragments-2.apk]
08-08 14:53:21.644: E/AndroidRuntime(13056):    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do the same in your layout XML:

```
<android.support.v4.app.Fragment />
```

Also, note the capitalization.

Comment: Now I am getting 08-08 15:27:28.653: E/AndroidRuntime(13644): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Fragment(Context,AttributeSet)

Comment: That's because there's no constructor like that.  Refer to this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html

Comment: @CodeDroid did you solve the problem with java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Fragment(Context,AttributeSet)? How did you do it?

Comment: This did not fix the problem for me, i keep getting the NoSuchMethodException and can not figure out how to fix it.

Comment: This is not a solution. This just produces different error.

Answer (score 1):

Check if your activity extends FragmentActivity?  android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity to be exact...

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue when using the fragment tag because I was missing the call to the super.onCreate() in my FragmentActivity. Adding it solved the problem:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> > My SDK is 4.03 but device is 2.3.

I too had this problem. Then I got to know that when we are running on a lower version of the device,we need to include support jar (android.support.v4) in the build path.

After including the Jar into the Build path, we also need to make sure that the jar file will be at the Top of the ordering( using Order and Export option of the eclipse).

These two things solved my issue.. Hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and here is the solution.


The activity using your fragment needs to extend `FragmentActivity` instead of just `Activity`.


In your layout for the activity, you can still use `<fragment />` instead of `<android.support.v4.app.Fragment />`