# Trying to add a fragment from another library - android

Tags: android, fragment, feedly

I am trying to add the following library:

https://github.com/infospace/android_oauth2_webview

to my project but I am getting an error:

```
Class is not a View android.support.v4.app.Fragment
```

(I also updated the v4 support libraries for the library and my project)
Here's my main page on project:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

tools:context=".MainActivity" >
<android.support.v4.app.Fragment
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:name="com.infospace.android.oauth2.AuthenticationFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     />

</RelativeLayout>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `FragmentActivity` instead of `Activity` if you are including `Fragment`s from the support library.

Comment: at first it was fragment which gave me: "Error inflating class fragment", until i saw http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11873794/error-inflating-class-fragment-class-not-found-android-view-fragment-but-i-am-in any other idea?

Comment: @dinbrca: Sorry, my answer was wrong; I saw this answer accepted on a similar question and copied it without thinking. Are you using `FragmentActivity` where this layout is inflated?

Comment: No.. The library uses Fragment and not FragmentActivity. Although - I have tried to convert it manually from Fragment to FragmentActivity and got another error..

Comment: @dinbrca: You need to convert your `Activity`s to `FragmentActivity`s if you are using `Fragment`s from the support library.

Comment: I already tried converting from fragment to FragmentActivity.. it gives me "Class is not a View android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity"

Comment: @dinbrca: You need to convert your **`Activity`** to `FragmentActivity`, *not* `Fragment`.